# Search for files dynamically in php

Tags: php

[image]

I basically want to search for a file on my computer. I know how to search but is there a fast way of searching a name and an extension without flooding my script with more than 2 for loops? the names (eg.. file,virus,node,misc) and the extensions will be added dynamically, Not through the source code.. the names will be in the thousands so i dont want to add them one by one, hence why i am doing it dynamically.

i was thinking:

```
foreach($names as $i){
  if (file_exists($i.".exe" | $i.".py" | $i.".js" | $i.".html" | )){
    //echo true or false}}
```

Like i said. I will be adding in extensions dynamically also. Would it be worth it having the code long with `file_exists(20 thousand extensions)` or just add them with a form?

Would it be a for loop inside another for loop?

Comment: You want to search the entire filesystem or just a certain directory/subdirectory? How often will you be doing this search?  How often will the files change?

Comment: certain directory, i'm looking for the proof of concept.

Comment: Are you wanting a solution that is only specific to a certain OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is on a linux server and you have the program 'locate', I would consider using that instead. It will save you a lot of load on your server and will return results a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using the Spl Iterators.

The following example is taken from the documentation of [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). It searches for a file called 'Yourfile.py':

```
$filename = 'Yourfile.py';

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/search_root/');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$regexiterator = new RegexIterator(
    $iterator,
    '/^' . preg_quote($filename) . '$/',
    RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
);

foreach($regexiterator as $fileinfo) {
    var_dump($fileinfo);
}
```

Comment: how would that search for a .py file?

I'm too noob to understand how regex works at the moment.

Comment: Have added `$filename` variable. Should be easier to use now. Even without having knowledge of regexes